# Cannot upgrade from mysql 8.0.28 to aurora-mysql 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.2.Specify a current active database version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am trying to create a aurora read replica from Amazon rds instance using aws console but getting this error: **Cannot upgrade from mysql 8.0.28 to aurora-mysql 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.2.Specify a current active database version, the latest active minor version for mysql 8.0 is 8.0.28.(Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 7fd68787-558c-4424-b784-f609306a40fb; Proxy: null)**

**Instance specifications: **
DB engine: Aurora - compatible with MySQL 5.7.12
DB engine version: 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.10.2
Instance class: db.r6g.4xlarge
Multi-AZ deployment: No

**Settings**
DB instance identifier: aurora-db-test

**Network & Security**

Virtual Private Cloud (VPC): default-vpc-fe66543
Subnet group: default-vpc-fe66543
Public accessibility: yes
Availability zone: no preference
VPC security groups:
Choose existing VPC security groups: default-VPC

**Database options**
Database port:3306
DB parameter group: default.aurora-mysql5.7
DB cluster parameter group:default.aurora-mysql5.7

**Encryption**
enable encryption

Account: 29x8xxxxxxxx
KMS key ID:6aaxxxxx-xxxx-49ca-xxxx-d648xxxxxxxx

**Failover**
Priority: tire 1

**Backup**
Backup retention period: 1 days

**Monitoring**
Enhanced monitoring: enabled
Monitoring Role: default
Granularity: 60 seconds

**Log exports**
Select the log types to publish to Amazon CloudWatch Logs
.Error log

**Maintenance**
Auto minor version upgrade: yes
Maintenance window: no preference

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and the error you are getting is because Aurora read replica is not compatible with MySql 8.0.28.

This [AWS doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.MySQL80.html) from 1 year ago seems to be the latest update for Aurora.

Furthermore, Aurora MySql version 3.02.2 is the latest version which shows is compatible with MySql 8.0.23. This is why you are getting the error message.
[image]